# Mix more then 1000 mp3's sounds bad / Can I use FFmpeg to merge 1000 mp3s?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, ffmpeg-php

I am working on a project where everybody has to activate a part of a song. I have about 7000 mp3's, each with the same length of the final mix but with only a small part of audio. So for example you can hear a drum hit at the 15th second and the rest of the mp3 (about 4 min.) is silence.

I use the mix filter to add all the mp3's. I add them 32 mp3s at a time. 
The first test I've run results in the first mixed mp3s to be silenced? (I set the Volume on the mix to the number of tracks) Also the sound is of poor quality after the mix. Can I fix this?

Or do you think this can not be done by ffmpeg? Do you know an alternative program to do this?

Thanks!
B.

Comment: Please don't tell me all of your source material is in MP3... if it is, you're pretty screwed here, and will have to get creative with noise gating.

Comment: I've mixed 4900 mp3's on a bitrate of 320. It sounds ok. The result is for a preview on a site so it does not have to be studio quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `amix` filter, add `normalize=0` at the end, before specifying the output file. This will make ffmpeg keep all the volumes of your audio inputs at the same level.